# change the window resize mouse button for kubuntu-desktop

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, kubuntu, kde

I am using alt + right click to resize windows. How do I change it to alt + middle click?

I am on ubuntu 12.04 using kubuntu-desktop i.e. kde plasma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

KDE System Settings > Window Behavior > Window Actions tab, Inner Window, Titlebar & Frame

[image]